# OSX Mail - deleting imap email without deleting on gmail server

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, imap

I am using Mail.app to access my gmail account (business / google apps email).

I want to delete a big pile of emails in Mail to clean up my inbox, but I want to keep those emails in gmail (IMAP server) so I look them up in the future by logging directly into gmail.

I'm new to Mail. Is there a setting where I can delete my emails in this account freely in Mail without deleting them at all from the gmail?

Answer (score 2):

You can check `Mailbox Behaviors` in your Gmail account setting (under `Accounts`) and check `Store deleted messages on the server`. This will make your messages still available in other clients even if you delete them in the Mac where you have this setting.

Reference: [Mail (El Capitan): Mailbox Behaviors preferences](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22347?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)